# How to add 2 items on the same "level" of a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf

So A tree view normally goes like this

```
|
| [Item]
| [Item]
| [Item]
```

But I need to be able to put 2 labels on the same *level* anywhere on the TreeView. For example"

```
|
| [Item] [Item]
| [Item] [Item]
| [Item] [Item]
```

Is this at all possible?

Here's my code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Room room = new Room(row);
                //MessageBox.Show(System.String.Format("Reaches {0}",room.roomNumber));
                roomList.Add(room);
                string cont = room.roomNumber.ToString();
                Label l;
                if (room.isVacant)
                {
                    l = new Label() { Content = cont, Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green) };
                }
                else
                {
                    l = new Label() { Content = cont, Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red) };
                }
                l.MouseDoubleClick += OpenRoom;
                l.Tag = tag;
                tag++;
                tv.Items.Add(l);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use a Container Control for the `TreeView` item like `StackPanel`, `Grid` etc and host multiple items in them, because a Content Control can have only one child

Comment: Post some sample code. An answer can be given based on what you already have.

Comment: ^ Oh alright, will do, sorry! Also, I'll try the Grid idea, thanks! I never knew you could do that. I'm new to C# you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<TreeView Name="tvMyTreeView">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label>First Label</Label>
            <Label>Second Label</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2"></TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I already went with the Grid idea you originally presented though and it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I was of help..:)